# Take Fbx from blender to three.js

Tags: .fbx, gltf, three.js

I have an fbx export from Maya which is perfectly working in Three.js . Fbx file exported from blender is not being imported in three.js. It is giving this error[image]

My client is working on three.js and he specifically wants files in fbx format. So I can not provide him gltf files.

The fbx I am exporting from blender is opening on web. I tested it here:
https://www.creators3d.com/online-viewer
What am I doing wrong, that the fbx file is giving error in three.js

Comment: If it helps persuade your client, the developers of three.js themselves [recommend using glTF](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models), FBX files are simply not as reliable on the web. That said, you may need to report a bug to the three.js to get help with this FBX file, including the `.fbx` or `.blend` file.